# cppcheck not detecting resource leak from epoll_create

Tags: posix, static-code-analysis, cppcheck

I am testing following resource leak with `epoll_create(1)` with Cppcheck *version 1.72*, but not getting any error.

```
#include "sys/epoll.h"

int main (){
   int i = 0;
   int epollfd = 0;
   while (i != 10){
      epollfd = epoll_create(1);
      i++;
   }
}
```

Can anyone let me know if cppcheck is not equipped with this kind of resource leak?

Answer (score 0):

I am a Cppcheck developer.

Cppcheck can detect such resource leaks. However currently the posix.cfg does not mention `epoll_create()` at all and therefore Cppcheck has no knowledge about this function.

Quick fix; create a epoll.cfg that contains the info about `epoll_create()` etc and use that when you run cppcheck (--library).

Proper fix; update the posix.cfg file (http://github.com/danmar/cppcheck/blob/master/cfg/posix.cfg). if you send me a pull request in github I'll be happy to apply it.

Cppcheck needs to know that `epoll_create()` allocates the file descriptor and how you deallocate it. I believe you use the `close()` method to deallocate it, so the needed configuration is something like:

```
  <resource>
    <alloc init="false">epoll_create</alloc>
    <dealloc>close</dealloc>
  </resource>
```